# How did I read .txt files and convert to a .xlsx files in matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, text

So I have this so far

```
file = fileread(filenames.txt) ;
data = textscan(file, '#:%2d  \t Area:%5d \t Xp:%4d  Yp:%4d  \t Length:%3d  B#:%2d  \t R:%2d  L:%2d  Ch:%2d  \t End 1:Xp:%4d  Yp:%4d  \t End 2:Xp:%4d  Yp:%4d\n') ;
data = [data{1}, num2cell([data{2:end}])] ;
xlswrite('filenames.xlsx', data) ;
```

but my text file looks like this (multiples files with varying rows this example has 9 plus the file index row)

```
File Index: 2095303
#: 1     Area:  939      Xp:-397  Yp: 586    Length: 99  B#: 2       R: 2  L: 0  Ch:-1       End 1:Xp:-450  Yp: 588      End 2:Xp:-352  Yp: 572
#: 2     Area: 1185      Xp:-287  Yp: 294    Length:145  B#: 2       R: 1  L: 1  Ch: 0       End 1:Xp:-317  Yp: 359      End 2:Xp:-235  Yp: 244
#: 3     Area:  592      Xp:-242  Yp: 486    Length: 77  B#: 3       R: 2  L: 1  Ch: 0       End 1:Xp:-278  Yp: 488      End 2:Xp:-202  Yp: 477
#: 4     Area:  818      Xp:-144  Yp: 480    Length: 60  B#: 2       R: 0  L: 2  Ch: 1       End 1:Xp:-181  Yp: 488      End 2:Xp:-135  Yp: 451
#: 5     Area:  377      Xp: -23  Yp:-443    Length: 37  B#: 1       R: 0  L: 1  Ch: 0       End 1:Xp: -42  Yp:-459      End 2:Xp: -12  Yp:-460
#: 6     Area:  923      Xp:  32  Yp:-234    Length: 67  B#: 1       R: 0  L: 0  Ch: 0       End 1:Xp:  -3  Yp:-260      End 2:Xp:  60  Yp:-212
#: 7     Area:  812      Xp: 150  Yp:-148    Length: 54  B#: 1       R: 0  L: 1  Ch: 0       End 1:Xp: 136  Yp:-130      End 2:Xp: 169  Yp:-161
#: 8     Area: 5968      Xp: 428  Yp: 432    Length:402  B#: 3       R: 3  L: 0  Ch:-1       End 1:Xp: 224  Yp: 468      End 2:Xp: 622  Yp: 356
#: 9     Area:  617      Xp: 714  Yp:  13    Length: 63  B#: 1       R: 0  L: 1  Ch: 0       End 1:Xp: 687  Yp:  35      End 2:Xp: 702  Yp: -22
```

I think the file index line is messing me up but I need that information too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's definitely an issue with the first line.
You'll need to process it separately, and start your second line with

```
data = textscan(file(22:end),...)
```

You may need to play around with the 22, it may be 21, or change depending on how the first line changes in your different files.
Note that, as documented, when using `textscan` on strings, it always starts at the first element of the string, not where you left off the last time you used `textscan` on the string.

Also, you may need to worry about the trailing '\n' in your format string.
Depending on your OS you may require '\r' instead of '\n'.

Finally, you will most likely find that after using `textscan` the data is in a cell array of vectors, and will need further manipulation to put into a format suitable for using xlswrite.

Comment: Or use the version of `textscan` that reads from an open file, and does respect the file pointer.